# How to set a (textFrame) pageItem in InDesign to update the position/size from the master page after it was manually changed in a page?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I have a script that does the following:

```
    var document = app.documents.item(0);
    var layer = document.layers.itemByName("Normal");
    var allTextFrames = toArray(layer.textFrames);
    var moved = selectWhere("moved", "label", allTextFrames)[0];
    var notMoved = selectWhere("notMoved", "label", allTextFrames)[0];
    var instance = selectWhere("instance", "label", allTextFrames)[0];
    $.writeln("Moved          : " + moved.geometricBounds.join(", "));
    $.writeln("Moved overr: " + moved.overriddenMasterPageItem.geometricBounds.join(", "));
    $.writeln("notMoved          : " + notMoved.geometricBounds.join(", "));
    $.writeln("notMoved overr: " + notMoved.overriddenMasterPageItem.geometricBounds.join(", "));



    var overr = moved.overriddenMasterPageItem;
    moved.geometricBounds = [moved.overriddenMasterPageItem.geometricBounds[0] 
                                            ,moved.overriddenMasterPageItem.geometricBounds[1]
                                            ,moved.overriddenMasterPageItem.geometricBounds[2]
                                            ,moved.overriddenMasterPageItem.geometricBounds[3]];
    moved.visibleBounds =      [moved.overriddenMasterPageItem.visibleBounds[0] 
                                            ,moved.overriddenMasterPageItem.visibleBounds[1]
                                            ,moved.overriddenMasterPageItem.visibleBounds[2]
                                            ,moved.overriddenMasterPageItem.visibleBounds[3]];
```

But then if I change the text frame in the master page it doesn't update the "moved" textframe...

For example there is a property for the pageItem that when is set to "-1" it will use the master page value. I was looking for something like this but for position and size.

fillTint    number  readonly    The percent of tint to use in the PageItem's fill color. (To specify a tint percent, use a number in the range of 0 to 100; to use the inherited or overridden value, use -1.)
src: http://jongware.mit.edu/iccs5_html_3.0.3d/iccs5/pc_PageItem.html

Answer (score 0):

**I will not mark as anwser because sometimes doesn't work;**

Here is the script that will remove the text frame and restores. Then it supply it with the data of the old textframe. It will also link the textframe to the previous and next textframe.

How to use:

- Create the script and paste the following
- Select the moved textframe and run the script.
- Done!!!

  ```
  #target "indesign"
  #targetengine "mySessionX"
  var SCRIPT_NAME = "Restore moved text frames";
  try{
  app.doScript(main, ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT, undefined, UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, SCRIPT_NAME);
  }catch(e){
      alert(e);
  }

  function main(){
      removeOverrides(app.selection[0]);
  }

  function removeOverrides(textFrame){
      if(textFrame.constructor.name != "TextFrame"){
          throw new Error("No text frame selected");
      }
      // save data
      var contents = textFrame.contents;
      var contentType = textFrame.contentType;
      var nextTextFrame = textFrame.nextTextFrame;
      var previousTextFrame = textFrame.previousTextFrame;
      var masterPageTextFrame = textFrame.overriddenMasterPageItem;
      var page = textFrame.parentPage;
      if(nextTextFrame){
          nextTextFrame.previousTextFrame = null;
      }
      if(previousTextFrame){
          previousTextFrame.nextTextFrame = null;
      }

      // remove overrides
      textFrame.removeOverride();

      // restore state
      var newTextFrame = masterPageTextFrame.override(page);
      newTextFrame.contents = contents;
      newTextFrame.contentType = contentType;

      // update right and left
      if(nextTextFrame){
          nextTextFrame.previousTextFrame = newTextFrame
      }
      if(previousTextFrame){
          previousTextFrame.nextTextFrame = newTextFrame
      }


      newTextFrame.recompose();
      alert("Restored");
  }
  ```